# Why do new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today).AddDays(4).Offset and new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today.AddDays(4)).Offset return different values?

Tags: .net, datetime, datetimeoffset

I'm currently in UTC+1 zone. TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset returns +1.

And `new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today).AddDays(4).Offset` returns +1.

But `new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today.AddDays(4)).Offset` returns +2!

Even more interesting that until plus four days offset is the same. Starting from four days call `new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today.AddDays(x)).Offset` returns +2 offset. 
Why?

```
//Same offset +1
var offset2 = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today).AddDays(7).Offset;
var offset22 = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today.AddDays(7)).Offset;

//Same offset +1
var offset3 = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today).AddDays(3).Offset;
var offset32 = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today.AddDays(3)).Offset;

//Different offset +1 and +2
var offset4 = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today).AddDays(4).Offset;
var offset42 = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today.AddDays(4)).Offset;

//Different offset +1 and +2
var offset5 = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today).AddDays(5).Offset;
var offset52 = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today.AddDays(5)).Offset;
```

Comment: Don't forget to put your clock forward on Sunday.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A more serious answer than my comment...

From MSDN:

> Because a DateTimeOffset object does not represent the date and time in a  specific time zone, the AddDays method does not consider a particular time zone's adjustment rules when it performs date and time arithmetic.

Therefore

```
DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today).AddDays(5)
```

does not change the timezone for the original date (Today = CET = UTC+1)

Also

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(5)
```

gives the local time in 5 days (CEST = UTC+2).

So

```
DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today.AddDays(5))
```

will give a time with the CEST offset (UTC+2)

Comment: Thank you! Your answer should be considered together with your comment. Today is Tuesday the 23 of Mars. And European summer time is within 4 days.